# What are data volumes?

Tags: data-storage, volumes

What are data volumes?

How would you define them?

How would you calculate the data volumes for a website.

Comment: Extend your question otherwise users will vote for closing because of not real question flag. Now it's hard to say if you mean SAP data volume or something different.

Comment: what are data volumes in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SAP, data volumes are the spaces defined in SAP to store data or log information.

Otherwise, the English word volume means amount.  A data volume is simply the amount of data in a file or database.

You would calculate the amount of data storage for a website by figuring out how much data comes in per month, and multiply that times the number of months you expect your web site to grow.

Most web sites just add disk storage as needed, rather than attempt to predict how much will be needed in the future.  If you're Google or Facebook, you just plan to add disk storage space constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this article](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=434) may help you, but still I would migrate this question to Webmasters part of the stackexchange.com if you're asking for a data volumes calculation for a website.